# how to auto resize/scale amazon aws ec2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling

currently am on the t2.micro & i read that amazon allow an auto scaling option to allow the server to expand/shrink according to the traffic which is perfect.

**so my question is:**

> what exactly should i do in-order to enable the auto scaling/resizing
>   of the server when needed or when the traffic start to spike ?
>
> is there an option to allow changing the instance type automatically ?
>
> auto scaling i believe means adding more instances and balance the load in between them, so does this mean i need to have a background about load balancing and all that jargon that comes with it or does amazon take care of that automatically ?

am totaly new to the whole server maintenance/provisioning land, so please try to explain as simple as possible. also the only reason i went with amazon because of the automation capabilities it offer but sadly their docs are very complex and many things could go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using the AWS management console. These operations are also possible using the Command Line Interface or AWS CloudFormation.

To **resize** an instance, you have to stop it then go to Actions > Instance Settings > Change Instance Type

As you can see, this operation is not automatic. In AWS you don't autoscale an instance but an autoscaling group which is a group of instances. So according to your memory/cpu usage, you can automatically start new instances (but not increase the size of the current ones)

To create an **autoscaling** group, go to Auto Scaling Groups in the EC2 menu:

[image: autoscaling groups in AWS management console]

To create an autoscaling group, you will need to create a Launch Configuration first which describes the properties of the instances you want to automatically scale. Then you will be able to define your scaling policies based on your Cloudwatch alarms (CPU usage, instance status...): 
[image]

Comment: good, many thanx but now there is also http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/attach-load-balancer-asg.html , would that be necessary or should i just stick with the basic auto scaling ?

Comment: It depends of your infrastructure. You may need an Elastic Load Balancer to distribute the traffic.

Comment: am sorry but i thought the auto scaling was suppose to do that , or is it a 50% of the equation & i will need to add the load balancing step anyway ?

Comment: the auto scaling group just takes care of the scaling. If you need a load balancer, you need to add one. It is not included in the auto scaling group.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to scale your instance and you don't mind about uptime, I can suggest this workaround.

TL;DR: set an alert on AWS CloudWatch to "ping" SNS when a specific alert is triggered (i.e. CPU, RAM > %) and setup a Skeddly action to automatic scale your instance when a SNS endpoint is pinged.

Details:

- subscribe to [**Skeddly**](https://www.skeddly.com/), a service to automate actions on AWS.
  It's free if you don't use it a lot;
- setup a "Change EC2 Instances" action and activate the SNS feature,
  then copy the SNS endpoint link; [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImWnP.png)
- be sure to clearly define the instance(s) affected by the action!
- go on AWS **Simple Notification Service** dashboard and create a new
  "topic", then select it and choose "subscribe to topic" from the
  Actions menu;
- you can paste here the SNS endpoint provided by Skeddly, then wait
  until the subscription is confirmed (it takes a while);
- now move to AWS **CloudWatch** and setup an alert for any metric that
  you find meaningful for your instance up/downscaling, i.e. CPU >= 90%
  for 1 day;
- for each alarm add a notification selecting the "topic" previously
  defined on SNS.

You are done!

Answer (score 2):

Auto scaling with EC2 assumes "horizontal" scaling, adding more instances to a auto scaling group

There is no well used, standard pattern for "vertical" scaling of increasing an individual instance size automatically.

In order to effectively understand and use auto scaling for your application yes, you "need to have a background about load balancing and all that jargon that comes with it".  See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html

Comment: dam it, okay , it there any link tutorial/video u can direct me to cuz i have already went through the doc and i felt lost :(.

Comment: @ctf0 maybe you could replicate behaviour you want by replacing your instance? you could hack existing AWS tools to do that automatically for you, but it's rather complicated and probably not what you want... just create a dummy load balancer, several launch configurations with the same AMI and different instance type and set up your alarms on e.g. CPU usage so that one autoscaling group will scale down (remove the instance) when CPU usage is high and another will kick in before that. for reverse use alarms on number of instances in the ELB and low CPU usage.

Comment: @grepe that sounds promising, i know its kinda big to ask but is there any chance u can make a small gist of the steps or a quick video to do exactly what u just mentioned, it will definitely help alot ;)